# Finding Total Load time of all assets from a Specific CDN

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to write a python script that will find the total loading time of all web site assets from a specific CDN. So in example I have a CDN called mystaticassets.com and I want to find the total time it took to load all assets from this CDN (Images, fonts, scripts, etc).

There are a ton of other assets on the page such as ad links, third party trackers but I do not want to count those. Only my CDN that I specify.

Is there a way to do this in python? I can only seem to find a way to count the total of all assets but how do I measure the performance of a specific CDN?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe waiting until all the assets you consider relevant to be loaded and calculating the elapsed time since hitting the page?

```
...
driver.get("mystaticassets.com")
start = time.time()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "asset1")))

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "asset2")))

...

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "assetn")))


end = time.time()
total_loading_time = end - start
```